# Google Cloud SQL: keeping dev and live databases updated

Tags: mysql, sql, eclipse, cloud

I have a local MySQL dev instance that I've been developing with and now I want my local MySQL table changes to be made in the live Google Cloud SQL instance that I have connected in my Google Plugin for Eclipse.  I can't figure out how to do this except for a full dump and import.  Is there another/better way?  Ideally, database versioning would be great, but I don't think that exists with Google Cloud SQL.